# Why I can not access an Element (which has been created by JS) using document.body.myElement?

Tags: javascript

```
let myElement = document.createElement("div")
```

I can access the element by:

```
myElement.anyMethod
```

But I can not access by:

```
document.body.myElement.anyMethod
```

So why can we access body by:

```
document.body.anyMethod
```

But we can not access the element by:

```
document.body.myElement.anyMethod
```

Comment: Why do you assume that your variable magically becomes a property of an unrelated object? `document.body.anyMethod` has nothing to do with `myElement.anyMethod`.

Comment: Your question has answered my question!
Thank you for your explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a step in your code if you're expecting to reference it from the DOM (via `document.body...` or `document.getElement...`). You need to append the element to a particular place where you want it. This [reference page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement#basic_example) shows a simple example, but I'll share an example related to your code here:

```js
let myElement = document.createElement("div");
myElement.innerHTML = "It works!";
// you can replace the following with `document.body.append(myElement)`
document.getElementById("body").append(myElement);
```

```html
<div id="body"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

### CreateElement

Let's make this simple. In DOM all the elements are treated as objects.
The document is also an object with attributes like body and methods like clear, location, and so on. So when you are creating an element with

```
let x=document.createElement('div')
console.log(typeof(x))
//returns object
```

The CreateElement returns an object and it does not create an attribute or anything for it. So the element is not connected to the document object.

### Methods

```
x.click()
```

X is an object of HTMLElement and has methods like click and attributes like id and so on. But when you are doing like this

```
document.body.x.click()
```

The document has an attribute named body but the body object has no attributes like x

```
document.body.x //returns undefined
```

So finally the createElement method returns an object but it doesn't add the element as its attribute so when you are calling like this you get an undefined error.